# Kafka Binder Configuration in Spring Cloud Stream and Spring Boot 1.5.7?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

Just trying to clarify my understanding of how to correctly setup the Kafka binder when using Spring Cloud Dalston SR3 and Spring Boot 1.5.x

1) Kafka broker configuration.

The correct place to define the broker configuration is now via the `spring.kafka.*` properties.

2) Zookeeper configuration.

If I am understanding this correctly, the zoo keeper configuration is required by the Kafka admin utilities and allows a Spring application to create topics and partitions automatically. It appears this functionality is unique to Spring Cloud Stream and not part of the core spring-kakfa library.

Question 1: If I have a spring cloud stream application that is NOT creating it's own topics, can I safely exclude the zookeeper configuration as well?

This would end up looking something like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          autoCreateTopics: false
          autoAddPartitions: false
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: kafka-dev-1.build.internal:9092,kafka-dev-2.build.internal:9092,kafka-dev-3.build.internal:9092
```

Question 2: If I do want my application creating topics/partitions, then I need to specify the core kakfa broker under `spring.kakfa.*` and the zookeeper config under `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder`?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
      zk-nodes: kafka-zoo-dev-1:2181,kafka-zoo-dev-2:2181,kafka-zoo-dev-3:2181      
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: kafka-dev-1.build.internal:9092,kafka-dev-2.build.internal:9092,kafka-dev-3.build.internal:9092
```

Comment: Everything sounds good for me. I would just go ahead and try the solution! And only if you have some problems come back here for questions.

Comment: Are you sure about configuring kafka via `spring.kafka`? Eg for brokers you could use `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers` (list).

Comment: If the Kafka libraries are on the classpath, the KafkaAutoConfiguration is going to kick in, so either you need to define the kafka properties it is expecting or disable the KafkaAutoConfiguration.